# My ubuntu installation failed because of too small partitions

Tags: partitioning

There was a warning about the partitions being too small but I ignored it so the installation failed. Now I need to remove the old half-finished install of ubuntu and reinstall it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Restart with the USB (or CD) you used to install; use the 'install ubuntu' option; then pick 'use the whole disk to install' in the partitioning screen. Job done.

Was there anything else going on, eg wanting to keep stuff? If so, you'll want to go into 'Try Ubuntu' to get a live system up, then run 'gparted' from the menu & manually re-arrange your partitions. When done with that, there is a desktop icon to install the system.

Comment: Sorry, should have said this earlier. I want to make it a dualboot with my already existing windows 7. So I don't want to mess with the partitions without knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: :) So follow the 2nd option; Assuming you started with only drive C: in windows, in `gparted` you remove anything with ext? format or linux swap, which probably leaves only /dev/sda1. If there is sufficient space, go to the installer; if not, Windows needs reducing in size - probably best to quit at this point, go to windows, backup, remove junk, check your disk, then return to gparted & resize /dev/sda1

Comment: Can I mess around and remove all of the partitions in gparted without breaking something in windows?

Comment: You can't move the Windows (ntfs) one, although you can resize it. If you remove it, that was Windows gone.. if you shift it & put another in front, eg make it sda2, Windows won't be happy. Microsoft are terribly arrogant and make assumptions about what's theirs... and take no considerationof other OS's

Comment: Don't resize the windows partition using gparted, I broke a system that way. Shrink it using windows tools, then boot the live cd to finish.